# Sometimes, my fragments are conflicting each other on UI. How to prevent it?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I don't know when it happens because it runs normally everytime I test it. But I'm sure it happens sometime. 
Here is `MapFragment`.
[image]

And Here's `LoginFragment`
[image]

That above two fragments like this, 
[image]

Not only these two but also some. 
Any idea?

Comment: Do you use add() or replace() in your FragmentTransactions?

Comment: Are you using autorotate on the fragments?

Comment: @Egor, I'm using replace.

Comment: @t0mm13b, yes, I use.

Comment: that is a lifecycle problem with the fragments which can happen and cause the fragments to overlay.

Comment: do you know how to solve it or prevent?